# about limit of the array output to file in c++

Tags: c++, file-io

I write a piece of code in c++ to test the limit of file output in 64-bit (redhat linux) system. The hard drive and memory are pretty big (1TB and 64Gb). I think the maximum size of the output file is 2^63 bytes since due to the 64bit address. I use sizeof to verify the following datatype in the c++ (g++ compiler)

```
sizeof(double) = 8, sizeof(size_t) = 8, sizeof(std::streamsize) = 8
```

The following code works good

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char data[200000][10000];

  fstream outfile("output.dat", ios::out | ios::binary);
  outfile.write(&data[0][0], 200000*10000);
  outfile.close();

  return 0;
}
```

But if I use double instead

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  double data[200000][10000];

  fstream outfile("output.dat", ios::out | ios::binary);
  outfile.write((char*)&data[0][0], sizeof(double)*200000*10000);
  outfile.close();

  return 0;
}
```

there is "segmentation fault (core dumped)" observed. But I don't understand why since sizeof(double)*200000*10000 < 2^63, so it should be ok for array of that size to be output.

Comment: The data structure you declared on the stack is too big for the stack.

Comment: do you mean the array is too big. I am confusing is the size of the array should be fine if it is less than 2^63 for 64 bit system (and if memory is enough)? I don't know what's the stack does but if anyway to output that big array? Thanks.

Comment: The stack is normally limited to a few megabytes or so. Even if you make it a global, 2^63 bytes requires (obviously enough) 2^63 bytes of backing store. That requires 2097152 drives (at 4 terabytes apiece) to act as virtual memory. I think it's fair to guess that you don't have 2 million+ 4 terabyte drives connected to your computer.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. So the only way to output such big array is to break it into pieces, right?

Comment: I am surprised that the `char` example worked.  That array is about 2 GB, declared on the stack.  I expect that it didn't work, but you had undefined behaviour.  In any case, please allocate giant chunks of data on the heap instead (using `new`).  You can ask for it in one contiguous chunk, and if you're lucky you'll get it.  On a 64GB system that isn't doing much else, you probably will.

Comment: yes, the char example works. Well, I am running that in the cluster which have big memory (I was told 64GB but I just read the specification it seems that it has more than 64GB).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your arrays are too big to fit on the stack, which has limited size no matter how much RAM you have. A quick-fix is to make them static. The better solution is to allocate them dynamically, either using new or vector. The fact your array is 2d makes it a bit tricky to pass a pointer to the file. Can you do this?

```
vector<double> data(2000000000);
fstream outfile("output.dat", ios::out | ios::binary);
outfile.write((char*)&data[0], data.size() * sizeof (double));
```

If this throws `std::bad_alloc` then your OS didn't have enough memory to provide.

Comment: I think you are right. I try your example and it seems work (it takes quite a long time to write the array to the file but it didn't return error so far). But I still don't understand if it is because of '2D' or not? Will be work if I use 1D array of 2000000000 instead of std::vector?

Comment: @user1285419 Vector is only 1d. If you want 2d, then either you make one big vector and do an index calculation [x + y * xsize] (you can wrap this in a class), or you make `vector<vector<T>> v(ysize, vector<T>(xsize)` which lets you access as `v[y][x]` but the whole array is NOT contiguous in memory, so you cannot take a pointer to the beginning and output in a single file operation.

Comment: @user1285419 Maybe I don't understand what you said. The cause of the problem isn't 1d/2d. A 1d array on the stack will give the same problem. `double data[2000000000]` will not work either.

Comment: oh, I see, I don't know that memory assigned for vector is not continuous. Thanks for pointing that out and it works with vector.

Comment: @user1285419 Within a vector, memory is contiguous. But if you use a vector of vector to create a 2d array, the whole memory is not contiguous. This is because each vector makes its own allocation.